# Cannot deploy asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, deployment, .net-4.0

### When I create a ASP.NET Web Application (using .net framework 4) in visual studio and I deploy it as is, I get the following exception:

[image]

Note that I am not doing any modifications to my application I select that project and right away I deploy it.

I am running IIS on Windows 7 Home Premium. So this error looks to me as if my version of IIS does not support the .net framework 4.0 .

The next thing I did was to find out what version of IIS I have. In order to do so I launched IIS Manager, clicked on help and then on about. The window that I got was:
[image]

**That looks to me as if I am using IIS 7.5**

Why is it that a default asp.net application will not run in my IIS? when I create a similar application using a .net web application but this time with the .net framework 2.0 . IIS does not complain when I see it in the browser.

---

### edit

---

Sorry I am new to asp. Ok I updated my application pool to V4.0 . after doing that I restarted the site and when I browse it I got a different error:

[image]

Comment: Have you setup the application pool for the site to use .NET 4.0?

Comment: No I have not. I get a different exception now. I will work on an update soon. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From researching at the last error I found at that my ASP.net installation was not registered correctly. I tried the following and it worked.

```
run %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

that solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

The app pool isn't setup for ASP.NET 4, look at the error message 'Version Information' you displayed, it's using 2.0.  Change this to 4 in the 'Application Pools' option in the IIS Manager.

Comment: that was definitely a problem. after doing that I got a different error. take a look at my edit. Thanks so much for the help.